# Can information from Cognito Forms be exported to Excel?

Tags: cognito-forms

Can the information from these forms can be gathered and then exported into Excel?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Yes, entry data can be exported into Excel by going to the Entries page and selecting 'Actions' then 'Export' you have the option to select 'All Fields' or just the 'Current View'. We do cover this in our [Help Content](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/77/entries/exporting-entries).